# ListView with multiple Buttons per view requiring scroll to multiple interactions

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.android

I have a `ListView` which is populated by two types of `Views` depending on the content to be displayed at the given position.

I have a `HeaderView` and a `DetailView` which have the following xml structure:

---

### `HeaderView`

```
LinearLayout
    ImageView
    LinearLayout
        TextView
        ImageView
    ImageView
```

---

### `DetailView`

```
RelativeLayout
    Button
    LinearLayout
        LinearLayout
            LinearLayout
                TextView
                TextView
            LinearLayout
                LinearLayout
                    TextView
                    TextView
                TextView
            ImageButton
    ImageView
```

---

Now, in the `DetailView` the `ImageButton` is used to add an item to a list in memory. The first time it's tapped it works as it should - it has the *click* effect and the event is fired -, but after the first tap, no matter how many times I tap it again, it does not work - does not show the effect of being clicked nor the event is fired.

If I attempt to scroll the `ListView` the pending effects start happening and the events are fired the same number of times I've tapped the `ImageButton` after the first time.

Even after the scroll, it *blocks* again and I need to scroll again to dispatch the pending events.

For the sake of simplicity, I've only made a simplified tree structure of the xml contents. If a more detailed version is required, say so.

Answer (score 0):

It should work without any problems, i've done things like this in the past with no problems.

There might be something wrong with your inplementation. Are you using the imageButton onClickListener and the listView onItemClickListener at the same time.

Normally when trying to use this kind of touch control you will need to be aware of the touch intersection. For more information

https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html

Comment: I'm using the `Click` (_Xamarin/C#_) / `onClickListener` (_Java_) events on the `Button` and `ImageButton` on the `DetailView`. Is that it? But still, I've had this problem even when I had only the `Button` in the `DetailView`. I'm not using other events/listeners there.

Comment: Not sure about Xamarin, but in Android if an Touch event returns true this stops the propagation of the touch to the child views. One of your touch handlers might be stopping the propagation. Here is the xamarin docs for handling touch events https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiresponder#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan%3awithEvent%3a

Comment: I'm using only the `Click` event. Should I handle also the `Touch` event? Also, what you've send is the documentation for iOS `UIResponder`. **EDIT**: Don't worry about the association Xamarin/C# <-> Java, I'll find out the method that should be used.